# Flow control and DCB structure

Tags: windows, serial-port

Windows HyperTerminal COM port settings dialog contains Flow Control combo with the following values: Xon/Xoff, Hardware, None.

How these values are related to DCB structure? I don't see any member in this structure that I can fill with these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xon/Xoff:  fTXContinueOnXoff, fOutX, fInX, XonLim, XoffLim, XonChar, XoffChar

Hardware:  fOutxCtsFlow, fOutxDsrFlow, fDtrControl, fDsrSensitivity, fRtsControl

Comment: Thanks. Can you give more details? What values exactly should I set in DCB for every Flow Control value?

Comment: I don't recall ever having used those flags or fields.  I can read the same MSDN page that you can read, and I can do the same experiments that you can do.  No wait, I can't, none of the PCs near me have serial ports.  It's not a lost art though.  One of my colleagues has to use a cellular modem while on the road, and it has a built-in UART.

Comment: OK, it's quite enough to set all these fields to 0.

Comment: It would be great if you would wrote for NONE. Do you have any knowledge about the NONE flags or can you refer any place i can read and understand the concept. Thank you!

Comment: No, worries! i have found the answer. If it will be required for someone else in the future the flags for NONE are as below:

      `_DCB.fInX = _DCB.fOutX = 0;
      _DCB.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;
      _DCB.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;`

Thank you!